Phase shift full-bridge converter
During t3-t4, only Q3 is ON shown with black arrow.
On the bottom-right of the picture, primary voltage and primary coil current increases towards negative.
I don't understand how the primary waveforms increases in negative way with only Q3 on?
During t3-t4, Cds of Q1 charges and Cds of of Q2 discharges.

Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2F9BsGcD1Ok&t=581s

Source: https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slua107a/slua107a.pdf?ts=1726667235613

The picture looks wrong to me. Maybe find a better resource.

I don't recognize your image as showing normal phase shifted PWM. From my own notes, it should look more like this (a resonant version): -




I add another source which is taken from texas application, they look same, what do you think @Andy aka

My answer provides a source that I know to be accurate.

In your schematic, ı dont see only one mosfet is open this is the difference. @Andy aka

Apart from the dead time, there should always be two activated MOSFETs @Mhan

@Andyaka I don't see any source given in your answer other than "my notes"

@KenGrimes if you are unhappy with this then you should flag my post for moderator action.

@Andyaka it would be a lot easier overall, and help the moderators as well,  if you would interact with the user over the query re the source rather than ramping up. This is a  can pretty ambiguous situation which the moderator would have to dig into and waste unnecessary time on. Working together would be appreciated.

@RussellMcMahon I regarded it as a serious criticism from Ken however, I didn't see it at all as warranted and recognized that if I just took the opposing stance it would likely escalate. I have no way to deal with this serious criticism other than taking the opposing stance hence, to avoid this I chose to suggest moderator action. I can't remember whether it was ken or me who raised it to you guys but, given my inability to see any other way forward, that's what I suggested he did. Maybe he did and maybe you could suggest how I could have handled it in a way that wouldn't result in mod action

Maybe you could also suggest what you said to ken given that what you have said to me is in full sight of all participants. I think that would be a very fair thing to do. In other words don't blame the suggester but blame the person who took mod action in the end (I think it was probably ken).

Have a downvote for your poorly sourced answer. You could have saved yourself a downvote if you'd simply stated your source rather than invoking the moderators for something you have to fix anyway.

@Null didn't you read the bit where I said (in my answer) From my own notes. Please explain your badly targeted downvote. Do you understand what my own notes" means. And also, I only suggested to Ken that he should flag for moderator action if he was unhappy. Why are you blaming me for something I have not done? This is unfair and appears to be a case of moderator abuse. Please explain what I need to fix.

@Andyaka I honestly feel that you are ramping up what started as minor into something which is getting out of hand. YES I know that sometimes standing on ceremony seems to be the right thing to do - ask my wife sometime about me on occasions ! :-). BUT from where I'm looking it doesn't seem that what Ken said was serious criticism. Really. He said 'I don't see any source given in your answer other than "my notes" ' --> I feel (perhaps wrongly) that something like "I drew the diagrams" would have been a good reply. Arguably you are not obliged to say that IF you did draw them, but it closes ...

I don't get any of this and I regard it as harassment. Nothing you guys are saying makes any sense at all. It boils down to plain and simple language (that I put in my answer when I wrote it).... From my own notes. What could be clearer and why are you guys making such a petty-minded big deal about this (other than trying to harass me into leaving the site) @RussellMcMahon

... the loop. || Instead you said --> " if you are unhappy with this then you should flag my post for moderator action." || I think that system rules do not allow me to confirm or deny things like flags BUT if Ken or anyone else flagged the question thay were following your suggestion. || I have said nothing to anyone else. || You may have noticed that I tend to make comments to people publicly. I do so more than most (maybe all?) others. And I also almost never send private moderator messages.  The rules/guidlelines actually suggest that public messages are preferred. I realise that this ...

... can be uncomfortable for any / all the people I interact with in this way BUT I think I think that it helps make the processes more visible to all and allows all to feel they are part of the process.. || Re Harassment: My AIM / desire is to help / damp things down / firefight where needed. || I don't always get it right. Sadly. I can sympathise with your angst (I've been angstified enough in life myself) but PLEASE, stop now. This should be and have been a minor thing but it's escalating dangerously. || Re "what could be clearer" --> eg "I drew the diagrams" as above.

@Andyaka I did read "from my own notes", but that is not a clear citation of a source. In my own notes I have material from a wide variety of sources, so for me to simply cite "my own notes" would give the reader no idea where it actually came from. Either cite the original source or claim that you drew the diagrams yourself, as Russell suggested.

@Andyaka  Once more: It happens that you are more technically capable than most site members. When you say "from my own notes" there is a strong likelihood but not certainty that you drew them - we know that you could write a book on the subject. || BUT ON AVERAGE if someones says "from my own notes" there is a reasonable chance that this is just a lazy way to post an uncited work. || Rather than having SOME people able to say xxx and for us to accept it as 'probably true', but not most people, it makes life far far easier if even the most capable help by doing as the rest necessarily do.

Please point me to some policy or precedent so that I can see that this is not an on the hoof decision that has evolved to get at and harass me because that's sure what it feels like. I feel bullied here. If you had a precedent prior to this debacle starting, why didn't you immediately point me to it @RussellMcMahon rather than dragging this on and on.

@Andyaka rRe "Please point me to ... " --> There has been much 'pointing to' both here and previously. Addressing here ONLY the citation issue. I honestly would have expected this to beclear tyo you both in general well stablished site piolicy and as explained specifically in this instance. || The policy of citation of sources is a SE policy in the rules. I'll assume you know that, everyone needs to, it is pointed out to everyone who does not seem to understand it on every occasion when it is noticed. I'm sure that you are aware of this. ||

An important issue is that we should TRY to treat all members equally. If new user 31415927 says that a diagram is "from my notes" or similar long experience of 'people' will tell you (and us) that that MAY mean "I drew the diagrams myself" but too often means "I am lazy, I copied it from somewhere, it's in my notees, go away".  || Attempting to have a graded scale of who one trusts to not plagiarise places an unnacceptabvle and unnecessary load on admins and the system. (eg I claim to NEVER knowingly plagiarise. Should I be treated differently to most?).  ... -->

... It (really) is a simple thing for users if such a situation to occur to respond with "I drew the diagram(s). Experience of life shows that some may say this and it will not be true. If YOU say it we could be confident it was true. If unknown members say it we would very very very likely assume it was true unless it was shown otherwsie in some manner as there is a limit to what can reasonably be done. || SO I considerand others consider and it SEEMS resonable to ne that for ALL users (certainly not just you) that the reasonable divide lies between "from my notes" and "I drew the diagrams".

... It would certainly have been far easier on all concerned (me, you, uncle Tom Cobbly and all, ... :-) ) if you had just gone the extra 0.01 mile). || You say that you considered Ken's query as "serious criticism". I honestly didn't see it as "weighty". He MAY have meant it as such and he may not. "Ancient wise men"* adumbrate that a gentle accurate answer when you have the moral high ground may infuriate nay sayers. That's liable to be more satisfying than calling in the mods in a situation when they should try hard to treat you the same as they would anyone else.  [[*Romans12, Prov 15]]

@Andyaka  Sorry - didn't answer 1 of your questions.  I Checked time line. 1st commented on ctober 13th at 1904 UTC. Now ~= 35 hours later. I've so far put several hours effort into this (almost certainly not obvious.) With the different time zones and the occasional need for nutrition and sleep I've tried to do what seemed best step by step to 'damp things down'. I have given this something close to " my best shot" overall. Never good enough. Alas. My aim is to TRY to ensure that things work well and equally well for as many users as possible. You and others equally.

I said "from my own notes" and you seem to be missing that all important word. In other words from notes that I (personally) own.

@Andyaka  Please read my comment posted 8 hours ago that starts "Once more: It happens ..."|| Also from 1 hour ago "An important issue ..." . || Also the whole series that I posted an hour ago. ||I'm genuinely surprised and puzzled that you insist on pursuing this. It SEEMS to me (and I'm well aware or how perspectives can vary) that the matter is very clear and that what has been asked is clearly consistent with (1) Meeting SE site policy and (2) Treating ALL users equally. || As before - IF user 31415927 said "from my own notes" IT WOULD BE CHALLENGED. "I drew the diagrams" would not be.

I have found nothing on how to correctly cite my own notes (or images) on SE
