Is there a need for a surge protection device in this panel?
This is the drawing of a panel that would be installed in a CNC workshop on the basement floor within an industrial facility with a busbar system. this panel will be used for energizing LED lighting and power sockets (3 phase and 1 phase). there is no surge protection device in the drawing, would this present a problem especially for the LED drivers?
I have checked the rest of the panels for the facility, there are no surge protection devices in any of the panels' drawings.



the above images are my property.

Has the designer been contacted to see if he designed the panel accordingly for the relevant surge zone it is intended to be installed in? You need to leave a citation for the diagrams if you don't own them (a site rule).

this panel will be installed in a CNC workshop inside the facility. in the basement. I have checked the rest of the panel drawings for all the facility, there are no surge protection devices anywhere.

@Andyaka These look like they are the OP's images, if the look like they are from an outside source like a text or presentation then flag. If they look like a screenshot of software the OP has, don't flag

@Andyaka these are drawings that were supplied by the project contractor's engineer. there is nothing here to cite. I own these drawings

@VoltageSpike so they don't need to have any citation at all then? Are you saying that OP owned images or self-drawn images do not need to have words that say something like "I drew the image" or "I own the image"?

Usually you can tell if they are screenshots and where the material is coming from. Has someone indicated that every image needs a citation?

@VoltageSpike as you are a moderator I would have thought you'd have seen this series of moderator comments under an answer I gave: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/727355/phase-shift-full-bridge-converter/727361#727361 <-- I mean I said the image came from my own notes but, two mods hauled me over hot coals in the comments for not  being more explicit.

Did you draw those images? I could see why, because they look like they come from a different source.

Maybe you can explain what different source they might appear to come from and, in particular, for this question, how did you make that distinction @VoltageSpike

Can you answer my question?

They are from my own notes and that is more of a citation than what this question is giving and you are apparently accepting.

@Andyaka can you help me with my question please

@MECHA I refer you to my 1st comment about contacting the designer. An alternative and messier way to solve this is to employ an engineer to do a full assessment of the design to determine what surge rating it might have and, what surge zones (lightning protection zones) it should not be used in without added protection. You also need to understand what your intended use is i.e. what surge zone categorization is your intended use.

@Andyaka thank you very much sir
